# Why variables in thread's block have the same memory address? Cuda

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am wondering why they have the same memory address, when If I remember correctly, each thread has a own copy of created variable in this way:

```cpp
__global__ void
Matrix_Multiplication_Shared(
   const int* const Matrix_A, 
   const int* const Matrix_B, 
         int* const Matrix_C)
{   
    const int sum_value = threadIdx.x;
    printf("%p \n", &sum_value);
}
```

Output:

[image]

I am considering the case of one thread's block, for example with 2 and more threads.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: In my opinion, there is no clue to add more code, It is stupid simple

Comment: Only If needed, I can add a kernel execute line

Comment: You are printing the address of an `automatic` variable. This is created as scope is entered by the current thread. Probably this is simply being created on the stack as the function is called. So if you simply call this function repeatidly in a loop it will "probably" always have the same address as the stack has not changed. Are you calling the function with different threads in your example?

Comment: Yea, but if I am printing a value, then I have a different values printed out

Comment: Do you have an idea to make a printf of %p to show a different memory locations?

Comment: Yes, I have 32 threads runned at this block

Comment: And thats why It makes me curious, when I create a another one block then I have a two different addresses, but per block

Comment: <<<1,32>>> at this case

Comment: You are making all sorts of assumptions that probably are not true, like the fact that every thread has a different part of the same address space. GPUs have had TLBs forever. Why can't different threads have their own local address spaces with the MMU handling local to global address translation? And that is without whatever compiler optimization tricks that can skew trivial examples like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NVIDIA GPUs have multiple address spaces.

The primary virtual address spaced used by pointers is called the generic address space. Inside the generic address space are windows for local memory and shared memory. The rest of the generic address space is the global address space. PTX and the GPU instruction set support additional instructions for 0 based access to the local and shared memory address space.

Some automatic variables and stack memory is in the local memory address space. The primary difference between global memory and the local memory is that local memory is organized such that consecutive 32-bit words are accessed by consecutive thread IDs. If each thread reads or writes from the same local memory offset then the memory access is fully coalesced.

In PTX local memory is accessed via ld.local and st.local.

In GPU SASS the instructions have two forms:

1. LDL, STL are direct access to local memory given as 0-based offset
2. LD, ST can be used for local memory access through the generic local memory window.

When you take the address of the variable the generic address space address is returned. Each thread is seeing the same offset from the generic local memory window base pointer. The load store unit will covert the 0-based offset into to a unique per thread global address.

For more information see:

- [CUDA Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) section on Local Memory
- [PTX ISA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#generic-addressing) section on Generic Addressing. Details on local memory are scattered throughout the manual.

Comment: Greg, thanks again for your contributions. I have been using this technology for almost 13 years and I still learn something every time you post here.