# Why local memory doesn't work with dynamic parallelism?

Tags: cuda

From [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-dynamic-parallelism-api-principles/) article it is clear that it is incorrect to pass a pointer to CUDA local memory into dynamic parallelism kernel call. **I am wondering why this is the case.** According to [CUDA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#device-memory-spaces) both local and global memory regions are allocated in DRAM, so I see no reason why these pointers can't be accessed. The only difference is their lifetimes, but in the following example it is clear that the lifetime of `y` is longer than the lifetime of `bar`, but code anyway fails in runtime:

```
#include <cstdio>

__global__ void bar(int* y) {
    printf("y = %d\n", *y);
}

__global__ void foo(int x) {
    int y = 10; 
    bar<<<1,1>>>(&y);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

int main() {
    foo<<<1,1>>>(1);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Is this failure happens when threads on one SM try to access the local memory of threads from another SM? For example, if I pass the pointer to local memory from one thread to another through global memory (without dynamic parallelism), is it also incorrect to dereference this pointer?

Comment: Threads have their own individual private local memory address space. It isn't portable between threads and it isn't portable between dynamically launched kernels. That is why it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66373761/681865

Comment: "The only difference is their lifetimes"  => They have different scopes as well

Comment: I have closed this as a duplicate of the link I posted earlier. Greg Smith provides a comprehensive answer which describes how local addressing works and how there are multiple virtual address spaces on the GPU, which disproves the basic tenet of this question